# jQuery if container1 text matches to container2 id replace text

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to replace class 'a' numbers with class 'b' text and then remove rest of the class 'b'

```
<div class="a">
  <span>3376</span>
  <span>3372</span>
  <span>3374</span>
</div>
<div class="b">
    <span id="3376">Name 1</span>
    <span id="8351">Name 2</span>
    <span id="3372">Name 3</span>
    <span id="2156">Name 4</span>
    <span id="8406">Name 5</span>
    <span id="3374">Name 6</span>
    <span id="1740">Name 7</span>
</div>
```

so the result will be this:

```
<div class="a">
  <span>Name 1</span>
  <span>Name 3</span>
  <span>Name 6</span>
</div>
```

/* remove */

Comment: Sounds good. What have you tried?

Comment: Agree with @j08691, what have you tried? why didn't it work? then what?
I'm sure you dont mean to come across rude but what you just posted is this is what i want who will do it for me im lazy....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code should achieve what you're attempting:

```
$('.a span').each(function() {
    $(this).text( $('#' + $(this).text() ).text() );
});

// Now empty div.b:
$('.b').empty();
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5rgg8sw6/4/)

Notice that we use jQuery's [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function to loop over the collection of `<span>` elements inside of the `.a` element. Then, we set the matched element's text value to that found in the matching ID-referenced `<div>`.

As a short post-script, if you need to work with HTML too, you may replace the [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function with [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Comment: And: $('.b').remove();  =)

Comment: tempted to vote down only because you answered such a lazy question

Comment: @workabyte The question was relatively straightforward, and probably took less time to write than your comment asking the OP what he'd tried haha. Just figured I'd give something back - we can all be lazy from time to time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.

```
<div class="a">
  <span>3376</span>
  <span>3372</span>
  <span>3374</span>
</div>
<div class="b">
    <span id="3376">Name 1</span>
    <span id="8351">Name 2</span>
    <span id="3372">Name 3</span>
    <span id="2156">Name 4</span>
    <span id="8406">Name 5</span>
    <span id="3374">Name 6</span>
    <span id="1740">Name 7</span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.each($(".a").find("span"), function (c, d) {
        (function () {
            $.each($(".b").find("span"), function (f, g) {
                if ($(g).attr('id') == $(d).text()) {
                    $(d).text($(g).text())
                }
            })
        } ())
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you need to loop through both `.a span` and `.b span` elements?

Comment: It says for each element in a check each element in b, so there are two loops instead of just one.

Comment: No, you don't need a loop for that. Just using the ID selector will be sufficient. Please see my answer.

Comment: Your answer is valid, and I agree also it is more efficient code-wise.